# Buddypress: adding a new tab direct user to their author page

Tags: plugin-development, buddypress

> Hi, This is regarding buddypress adding new tab to the member profile
>   main nav and when is click direct user to the author posts www.mysite.com/Author/username/

After researching and looking I have find this [code](https://www.ibenic.com/add-new-tab-buddypress-profile-page/) that it kinder works, it creates a new custom tab and direct users to the new post but the URL is not what i'm looking for it creates member/username/mypost what I need is something like this www.mysite.com/Author/username/ I just don't understand how i can achieve this with this code below....

```
function ibenic_buddypress_tab() { global $bp; bp_core_new_nav_item( array( 'name' => __( 'My Posts', 'ibenic' ), 'slug' => 'my-posts', 'position' => 100, 'screen_function' => 'ibenic_budypress_my_posts', 'show_for_displayed_user' => true, 'item_css_id' => 'ibenic_budypress_my_posts' ) ); }
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-K1vGcH3gSY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your screen function `ibenic_budypress_my_posts` create a redirect.
Something like:

```
function ibenic_buddypress_tab() { 
    bp_core_new_nav_item( array( 'name' => __( 'My Posts', 'ibenic' ), 'slug' => 'my-posts', 'position' => 100, 'screen_function' => 'ibenic_budypress_my_posts', 'show_for_displayed_user' => true, 'item_css_id' => 'ibenic_budypress_my_posts' ) ); 
}

function ibenic_budypress_my_posts() {
    $url = '/author/' . bp_get_displayed_user_username();
    bp_core_redirect( site_url( $url ) );
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting a Error; Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)

Comment: Just to clarify I basically replace "ibenic_budypress_my_posts" with the code you have provide, I also tried to paste the code below it I still get the error 

unexpected 'ibenic_budypress_my_posts' (T_STRING)

Comment: I've adjust my answer.

Comment: Amazing Thank You so much shanebp it work. I really appreciate for your time THANK YOU :)